# Create Developer Story | "Next" button not working

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, developer-story

I am trying to [create my Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/create) so that I will have better job recommendations, but the "Next" button is not doing anything. I tried reloading the page a few times and changing all the text inputs, but nothing is working.

---

Just for clarity, I am talking about this button:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug; it is by design. The "Next" button isn't working because you haven't finished filling out all the fields on that form.

Specifically, the "Tech you want to work with" box requires a *minimum* of three tags to be entered; you've only entered one. There is an advisory message below it saying, "Add at least 2".

Perhaps that message should be made to render in red, so that it is more visible?

Comment: The fact that there doesn't appear to be a visible failure state, and that the only indication of input not being accepted is that the next button "doesn't work," seems to be pretty poor UI design IMO.

Comment: Also, it'd be nice that upon clicking it there would be some sort of feedback, for example highlighting the incomplete fields or validation messages. While it may not be a programming error, I'd consider this an UX bug, when a form entry doesn't pass validation, it should be clear that it failed, which fields failed, and why they failed. I don't think passing this off as status-bydesign is a good idea